# __weak pointer type holding on to the object even after strong pointer releases the same object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

After having declared the property as a weak type and then passing it as an argument in the removeObject: message, the "selectedLine" pointer is no longer supposed to hold on to the object that it was previously pointing to.
  After this line-

```
[completeLines removeObject:selectedLine]//completeLines is a mutable array here.
```

shouldn't the selectedLine pointer be pointing to nil immediately after this using the ARC principle. I already had made it weak type earlier.
Coz a removeObject: implementation must look something like this:

```
-(void)removeObject:(id)obj{//obj pointer now shares an object with (__weak)selectedLine pointer
  __weak id ptr;
   for (ptr in completeLines)
   {
      if(ptr==obj)
       obj=nil;// releasing a strong reference makes ptr as well as selectedLine automatically release the particular Line object.
   }
 }
```

But when I'm logging it to the console, the weak pointer still appears to hold to the object:-

```
  NSLog(@"%@", selectedLine);
```

In the console I see the details of the object when i should be seeing (null) instead, logged to the console.
 Pls anyone explain why is this the case..

Comment: Something else is retaining the object, other than the array.

Comment: array is retaining this object under ARC.

Comment: But the strong pointer (the parameter variable)-"obj" gets pointed to nil inside of removeObject:, and selectedLine is a weak type pointer.. So there is nothing else that could retain the object, is it?

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to do. Makes no sense to me. You call this method like `[foo removeObject:obj]` where `obj` is a strong reference retaining the object. You can't possibly release all the references inside the method.

Comment: I think i have made a blunder. I have fixed the problem.. I was logging the pointer details in the wrong part of the code.. Apologies for wasting your precious time..Need to be more careful from here on out.. Thanx for replies btw..

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because under ARC when you add weak reference to an array it holds reference of this object. If you want to weak reference inside array you should wrap this reference in a block. Like this:

```
typedef id (^WeakBlock)(void);

array = [NSMutableArray array];
obj = [NSObject new];

WeakBlock block = ^(void) {
    typeof(obj) __weak wObj = obj;
    return wObj;
};

[array addObject:block];

WeakBlock blockInArray = [array firstObject];
NSLog(@"%@", blockInArray());

obj = nil;

NSLog(@"%@", blockInArray());
```

Output:

```
2014-06-28 11:25:56.174 weak-array[18604:60b] <NSObject: 0x8c7fcb0>
2014-06-28 11:25:56.175 weak-array[18604:60b] (null)
```

Comment: Well in the removeObject: implementation above (the library version cud be alike) there are 3 pointers pointing to the actual object. The obj pointer which is of strong type and the other two both of which are of weak type: selectedLine pointer which is passed as an argument in the message removeObject: and then internal local variable ptr. So removeObject: method must internally have the strong pointer (there is only one i.e obj) release the object in the actual implementation so that the weak references i.e selectedLine and the local var also automatically release the object & point to nil.